# Creating a page dynamically

Tags: views, path-aliases

Using Views in Drupal 7 I can consume the output of a restful API. I want to take some of the data and dynamically create pages. For example I get the following return json:

```
$data = {'title':'This is a page title','alias':'pages/page-alias-name','content':'This is some content'}
```

I would want to dynamically create a page located at http://www.example.com/pages/page-alias-name which would have a title of $data['title'] and the content would be $data['content']. Is it possible to create pages dynamically like this. How can I go about doing this?

Additionally, if I had identical content stored in an external database that can be read by a custom Views module, can I do this and how would I go about it?

Comment: Do you have a way to get all of the data if given the alias?  Eg, in a menu callback if you can call a service that returns data given the alias, this is a trivial matter.

Comment: Yes, given an alias I can call the info dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you are using Views to do this, but with a custom module you could easily do this with a fairly simple [hook_menu()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7), eg, something along these lines:

```
function YOURMODULE_menu() {

  $items=array();

  $items['pages'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'YOURMODULE_get_some_rest',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );

  // any other menu items go here

  return $items;

}
```

and then:

```
function YOURMODULE_get_some_rest() {

  $args=func_get_args();

  if ($args) {

    $alias='pages/' . implode('/', $args); // so pages/foo works as does pages/foo/bar etc

    $data = /* get your data from your external service */ ;

    if ( /* $data was found */ ) {
    
      drupal_set_title( /* title in $data */ );

      return /* content in $data */ ;

    } else {

      return MENU_NOT_FOUND; // we don't have an alias of that name

    }

  } else {

    return MENU_NOT_FOUND;  // just called 'pages' so do something else here if need be, perhaps a list of all pages but for now, we just return not found

  }

}
```

so after a cache clear, users should now be able to go to `www.example.com/pages/alias` and Drupal will go out to your external service and grab the content and if found, populate the page with it, otherwise will return not found.

Now, if this data is going to be fairly static, I'd look into caching it so your users aren't delayed while Drupal fetches it.  For that, I'd look into [cache_set()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!cache.inc/function/cache_set/7) and [cache_get()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!cache.inc/function/cache_get/7).

ADDITION:

Drupal's menu system works on a sort of best fit methodology.  For example, if you define a menu item `foo`, it will obviously match `www.example.com/foo`, but, if no menu item has been defined for `foo/bar`, it will also match `www.example.com/foo/bar` or even `www.example.com/foo/bar/baz/bing` etc etc.

So, in my example above, I defined `pages`.  This will match `www.example.com/pages` which is just an error condition above, but with some programming could list all of the potential pages you have available to you, but also will match `www.example.com/pages/alias-of-page` or `www.example.com/pages/alias/of/page`.

Inside the callback, I use PHP's built-in function [func_get_args()](https://www.php.net/func_get_args) to deal with the variable number of arguments that can be passed to this function.  When you go to `www.example.com/pages`, no arguments will be passed to this callback and `func_get_args()` will return an empty array.  But, when you go to `www.example.com/pages/alias-to-page`, Drupal will automatically pass `alias-to-page` to the callback, and `func_get_args()` will return an array containing it, and when you go to `www.example.com/pages/alias/to/page`, it will pass three arguments, `alias`, `to`, and `page` to the callback function and `func_get_args()` will return an array containing all three.

As to your commentary question regarding this inside Views, once again, I'm not sure how your are doing this inside Views, but yes, this would go inside YOURMODULE.module and would stand alone outside of Views (although Views might be a great place to generate the listing on `pages` by itself).

Comment: I am a bit confused. What is $args taking as I can't see any function arguments being fed in. I also assume that the first function is put in the .module file? Sorry for the confusion I am very new at this. Also, how can I adjust this to take the value from a custom database feed using the $data from hooks_view_data?